# Preventing spam submission via form using a hidden field

Tags: jquery, forms, spam

My boss hates captcha's and well, so do I even if they work. She instead suggests using a hidden field so that if it is filled out [by robots] that the form should not be submitted. Are there downsides to this method?

Comment: I don't think is very hard for a bot to detect a hidden field is he wants to do it.

Comment: That doesn't really help me at all.

Comment: Are there downsides to this method? Yes, I don't think is very hard for a bot to detect a hidden field is he wants to do it. I'm answering your question.

Comment: We use coldfusion and moved to use CFFormProtect. Maybe your server-side language has something similar? CFFormProtect works wonders and doesn't require the use of a captcha.

Comment: Something else you might want to take into account is that non-human readers may be confused by hidden fields.

Comment: You can hide input with CSS and then it doesn't have attribute hidden, which is easy to read by bots. Or even add some value to input which is hidden by CSS and remove it with JavaScript, bot will send that value, but not humans. Of course it is possible that there is bot that can understand CSS and circumvent this protection.

Comment: I understood the logic - I just wanted to know drawbacks. I also took out the jQuery question in my answer because I read that most/all spam crawlers don't use js thus defeating the purpose.

Comment: If it reduces spam, what possible drawbacks could it have?  I think Claudio Redi fails to see that bots very rarely do everything that bots *could* do.  There is so much low-hanging fruit that if you manage to nudge your own fruit up by an inch or so, you go free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you described is typically referred to as a [honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29). While some sites have had success with them in the past your results will vary depending on the value of spamming your site. Also, with honeypots getting more widespread adoption spammers are using smarter pieces of software that can circumvent these types of traps. I suggest you take a look at this [proof-of-work service](https://www.spamcaptcher.com/captcha/faq.jsp#what_is_proof_of_work) that will allow you to use better bot fighting techniques that are still invisible to your users. That said, for things that have serious security implications (e.g. forgot password) I strongly recommend you use a CAPTCHA.

Comment: CAPTCHA won't necessarily prevent form submissions from a duplicated and stripped down version of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could trick any robot by exchanging the functions of the submit-button and the cancel-button:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // remove user values
});
$('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('form').serializeArray();
    data['human'] = true; // hidden value
    $.post('example.com', data);
});
```

Comment: Forms don't use cancel buttons though. If I didn't want to submit, I'd just leave the page

Comment: Well, you can simply hide the submit-button and put a `<button>` element on the site...